# Where is Pathauto's "Strings to Remove" stored in MySQL?

Tags: path-aliases

I've tried looking in the "variable" table with `SELECT name FROM variable` but I think it's not there.

Where does the module save that setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stored in the variable named `pathauto_ignore_words`, you can get it directly like this:

```
SELECT value FROM variable WHERE name = 'pathauto_ignore_words'
```

or using the Drupal API like this:

```
$ignore_words = variable_get('pathauto_ignore_words', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Clive mentioned, it is stored in the variable table, **but only after you save the settings for the first time.**

Before you save the settings, it is not found in the DB. By default it is stored in a constant within the module. [See the default ignore list for Pathauto 7.x-1.2](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/pathauto/tree/pathauto.module?id=e95ceafa6b4638084cc37aeaff268f117f84a111#n20)